# Configure STONITH for esxi host CentOS guests

Tags: vmware-esxi, high-availability, drbd

I am just doing some initial researching into STONITH and am finding that it can require Hardware to reset the failed nodes. Something called an IPMI can be used. I was wondering how something like this factors into a virtual environment? Does anybody have any experience implementing STONITH in an esxi 6 VM Environment?

Current Env Variables:

Esxi 6

CentOS 7

Pacemaker + Coroysync + DRBD configured

Looking to configure STONITH and wondering if somebody can help me understand how to do this in a virtual environment.

Comment: Did you do any research on your own? This is not really rocket science...as a starting point, have a look [on this](https://www.hastexo.com/resources/hints-and-kinks/fencing-vmware-virtualized-pacemaker-nodes/).

Comment: I do not have VCenter just esxi, can this be done without VCenter?

Comment: And no, I didn't' do any research, just figured out how to implement a HA Linux Cluster on my own...

Comment: Maybe I am googling the wrong thing, because I had trouble finding documentation, I am continue to research, but was hoping somebody had some familiarity with this setup that could guide me, I will check the link and look into install the SDK

Comment: Not sure if your irony is helpful in here, but anyway: Just try it out, and if you're running into specific problems which you're unable to solve on your own, report these here (or maybe better in a new question) to get people help you. Looking at [this](https://github.com/ClusterLabs/fence-agents/blob/master/fence/agents/vmware/fence_vmware.py) might be helpful as well, CentOS should provide this as well. Besides: I've never used ESXi, so can't tell you, if this will work or it won't.

Comment: The link you provided lead to me the VSpehere Perl SDK which I think is what I need to get this all to work, so I will test/install that and follow the guides and go from their, and perhaps edit this later with more specifics, or that might be enough to get me going

Comment: Alright - good luck!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers: Yes; good luck! Please do come back and answer your own question if you succeed. It's been a while since I've successfully configured fencing inside of vcenter and would like to know if it works well with v6.

Comment: @MattKereczman I got [vCli installed](https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/index.php/2016/05/04/install-vcli-6-on-centos-7-vsphere-sdk-for-perl/), but I think it requires VCenter which I currently don't have implemented, plus I'd rather not rely on VCenter for this, I wanted to have it go over the network over directly connected NIC's used for DRBD. Kinda went on a back burner tho, busy with other projects.